# Error trying to apply app_types to logical_types of add_dataframe at once

Tags: featuretools

```
app_types

{'TARGET': Boolean,
 'FLAG_MOBIL': Boolean,
 'FLAG_EMP_PHONE': Boolean,
 'FLAG_WORK_PHONE': Boolean,
 'FLAG_CONT_MOBILE': Boolean,
 'FLAG_PHONE': Boolean,
 'FLAG_EMAIL': Boolean,
 'REG_REGION_NOT_LIVE_REGION': Boolean,
 'REG_REGION_NOT_WORK_REGION': Boolean,
 'LIVE_REGION_NOT_WORK_REGION': Boolean,
 'REG_CITY_NOT_LIVE_CITY': Boolean,
 'REG_CITY_NOT_WORK_CITY': Boolean,
 'LIVE_CITY_NOT_WORK_CITY': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_2': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_3': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_4': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_5': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_6': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_7': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_8': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_9': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_10': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_11': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_12': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_13': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_14': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_15': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_16': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_17': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_18': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_19': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_20': Boolean,
 'FLAG_DOCUMENT_21': Boolean,
 'REGION_RATING_CLIENT': Ordinal,
 'REGION_RATING_CLIENT_W_CITY': Ordinal}
```

I am trying to apply the above dictionary, `app_types`, to `logical_types` of `add_dataframe` at once. so, I wrote the following code, but I get the following error:

```
import featuretools as ft

es = ft.EntitySet(id="clients")

es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe_name="app_train", dataframe=app_train,
                      index="SK_ID_CURR", logical_types=app_types)
```

```
TypeError: Must use an Ordinal instance with order values defined
```

I want to apply `logical_types` at once, how can I do that? This error only occurs for ordinal columns

`REGION_RATING_CLIENT` and `REGION_RATING_CLIENT_W_CITY` columns of `app_train` have 1, 2, and 3 as values and are integer types.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question.

In order for the column to be assigned the `Ordinal` logical type, you must provide an `order` argument, specifying the ordering of values from low to high.

Since you mentioned the column only takes on the values 1, 2, and 3, you can try changing the last two entries in the `app_types` dictionary to:

`'REGION_RATING_CLIENT': Ordinal(order=[1, 2, 3])`

`'REGION_RATING_CLIENT_W_CITY': Ordinal(order=[1, 2, 3])`

You can reverse the `order` array if you want 3 to be considered lowest, and 1 to be considered highest.